# Can I freeze Parmesan?

Tags: cheese, freezing, parmesan

I am thinking about buying a larger amount of Parmesan and freeze it for later use. Is this possible? How long can I keep it for? How is the taste/texture affected?

Comment: Hi Sven, I edited your question so all the unrelated content is out. I also added some more questions, to have more question. If it's not alright with you, just say so or come to the chat room.

Comment: Related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4984/can-you-freeze-cheese-and-still-keep-the-flavor-when-you-defrost-it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can freeze parmesan cheese. Even without freezing, Parmesan is very durable since the low water and high salt content prevents mould from growing. The younger varieties may be more prone to mould growth (having a higher water content), but I've kept ripe Parmesan (30-36 months) for at least a year in the fridge without problems (and it would probably have stayed good much longer). Just remember to keep it wrapped in paper, not in a sealed plastic container to prevent a buildup of condensation.

Comment: Personally I wrap in a paper towel and then in a plastic bag, occasionally changing out the paper towel to prevent moisture buildup. I do this because when it's sealed in a plastic bag, I can toss it in the fridge wherever I like instead of carefully wrapping in paper and placing it on a nice flat surface.

Comment: Tough stuff, Parmesan. You could probably build a n interior room, out of it. As long as it stays dry, and unoxidized, it should be fine. It doesn't oxidize easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to add much as Tor-Einar Jarnbjo's answer was very thorough but just to note that you can also freeze parmesan rinds to add to soups and stews for an easy umami boost.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to freeze it. Keep it dry and cool and everything will be just fine.

I make artisan cheeses...cool and dry is how it is aged and is all it requires.

Comment: How cool and how dry? And how to keep it that cool and that dry? Is a regular refrigerator cool and dry enough?